# MySQL and Kayako Database:

Tags: mysql

The query below works a treat, however I would like to add into the mix based on a date range, for instance how many closed tickets today?

```
Select count(*) from swtickets
 inner join swdepartments on swtickets.departmentid = swdepartments.departmentid
 inner join swticketstatus on swtickets.ticketstatusid = swticketstatus.ticketstatusid
 inner join swticketpriorities on swtickets.priorityid = swticketpriorities.priorityid
 where
 swdepartments.title = "IT Support Desk" and
 (
  swticketstatus.title = "Resloved"
  OR
  swticketstatus.title = "Closed"
 )
```

Comment: Do you have a date or timestamp column? You will need a column with some sort of date format if you want to get that kind of information. I don't think mysql stores this data automatically.

Comment: Many columns, date doesn't standout. This is for the Kayako MySQL database. Trying to make a counter of how many tickets closed by date via MySQL query.